# $f : M → M$ be a transitive continuous transformation, if $\phi \circ f=\phi$, then $\phi$ is constant.

Tags: proof-verification, continuity, metric-spaces

We say that $f$ is transitive if there exists some $x ∈ M$ such that $ \{ f^n(x) :
n ∈ N \}$ is dense in $M$.

Let $f : M → M$ be a transitive continuous transformation in a compact metric
space, and $\phi:M \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ continuous. If $\phi \circ f=\phi$, then $\phi$ is constant.

**Attempt**:I have tried to show that $ \phi (x) = \phi (y)$ for any $y$ in $M$. Using the orbit of $x$ is dense in $M$, I find a sequence $f^{n_s}(x)$ converging to $y$. Then using that $\phi \circ f=\phi$, by recursion we obtain $\phi \circ f^n=\phi$. Then $\lim\limits_{s \to \infty} ( \phi \circ f^{n_s})(x)=\phi(x) $, but by continuity $\phi (\lim\limits_{s \to \infty} f^{n_s}(x))=\phi(x)$ implying $\phi (y)=\phi(x)$.

I imagine the proof is something of that kind, because the fact of being  $ \{ f^n(x) :n ∈ N \}$ dense, and of equality $\phi \circ f^n=\phi$ says that $ \phi(x)$  coincides with almost every point in $M$. Does anyone have any better suggestions?

Comment: To me, this is already better.

Answer (score 2):

Since $\phi\circ f=\phi$, for every integer $n$, $\phi\circ f^n=\phi$. This implies that $\phi(f^n(x))=\phi(x)$, we deduce that the restriction of $\phi$ on $Y=\{f^n(x)\}$ is constant, and $\phi$ is constant on the adherence $\overline{Y}=X$ of $Y$.

Comment: It suffices that $M$ is a Hausdorff space. If $X$ is $any$ space and  if $M$ is Hausdorff and if $f:X\to M,\, g:X\to M$ are continuous then $\{y\in X: f(y)=g(y)\} $ is closed in $X$... With $X=M$ and  with $g(y)=\phi(x)$ for all $y\in M.$...+1